# Proper way to dispose DbContext when one method calls another and both use DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm confused about the proper way to dispose my DbContext when one method is calling another.  These both get called independently, which is why DeleteSheet is separate.  However, DeleteChain calls DeleteSheet to remove children when the parent (Chain) is deleted.

I try to dispose in each method, but when I run DeleteChain I get:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

on

```
db.Chains.Remove(chain);
```

I'm guessing it's because I disposed of it in DeleteSheet when removing the children.

Here are my methods:

```
public class ControllerHelper
{
    private UranusContext db = new UranusContext();

    public void DeleteChain(int? chainId)
    {
        var chain = db.Chains.Include(c => c.Sheets)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChainId == chainId);

        // Removes sheets (children)
        foreach (var sheet in chain.Sheets.ToList())
        {
            DeleteSheet(sheet.SheetId);
        }

        db.Chains.Remove(chain);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Dispose();
    }

    public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId)
    {
        var sheet = db.Sheets.Include(s => s.FileDetails)
            .Include(s => s.SheetsCounties)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SheetId == sheetId);

        foreach (var fileDetails in sheet.FileDetails.ToList())
        {
            db.FileDetails.Remove(fileDetails);
        }

        foreach (var sheetsCounties in sheet.SheetsCounties.ToList())
        {
            db.SheetsCounties.Remove(sheetsCounties);
        }

        db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
        db.SaveChanges();

        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

How do I properly dispose of DbContext in this case?  I'm confused since if I only dispose in DeleteChain and then DeleteSheet is called outside of DeleteChain, it won't dispose.

Edit: Attempt #2.  I wrap each in a using and dispose of them individually.  However, when I delete the children in `DeleteSheet`, `DeleteChain` doesn't realize I did that and throws: `The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.` on `db.SaveChanges()` in `DeleteChain`.

Attempt #2.

```
public void DeleteChain(int? chainId)
{
    using (UranusContext db = new UranusContext())
    {
        var chain = db.Chains.Include(c => c.Sheets)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChainId == chainId);

        // Removes sheets (children)
        foreach (var sheet in chain.Sheets.ToList())
        {
            DeleteSheet(sheet.SheetId);
            //db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
        }

        db.Chains.Remove(chain);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId)
{
    using (UranusContext db = new UranusContext())
    {
        var sheet = db.Sheets.Include(s => s.FileDetails)
            .Include(s => s.SheetsCounties)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SheetId == sheetId);

        foreach (var fileDetails in sheet.FileDetails.ToList())
        {
            db.FileDetails.Remove(fileDetails);
        }

        foreach (var sheetsCounties in sheet.SheetsCounties.ToList())
        {
            db.SheetsCounties.Remove(sheetsCounties);
        }

        db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to move sheet deletion logic in separate method and call it from both DeleteChain and DeleteSheet, like this:

```
public class ControllerHelper
{
    public void DeleteChain(int? chainId) {
        using (var db = new UranusContext()) {
            var chain = db.Chains.Include(c => c.Sheets)
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChainId == chainId);

            // Removes sheets (children)
            foreach (var sheet in chain.Sheets.ToList()) {
                DeleteSheet(db, sheet);
            }

            db.Chains.Remove(chain);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId) {
        using (var db = new UranusContext()) {
            var sheet = db.Sheets.Include(s => s.FileDetails)
                .Include(s => s.SheetsCounties)
                .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SheetId == sheetId);

            DeleteSheet(db, sheet);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private void DeleteSheet(UranusContext db, Sheet sheet) {
        foreach (var fileDetails in sheet.FileDetails.ToList()) {
            db.FileDetails.Remove(fileDetails);
        }

        foreach (var sheetsCounties in sheet.SheetsCounties.ToList()) {
            db.SheetsCounties.Remove(sheetsCounties);
        }

        db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems the most viable and works. I just have one question: When you pass UranusContext db, doesn't it create a new instance of UranusContext?  Is that disposed of or add any unnecessary overhead?

Comment: No, when you pass a reference to context - nothing is created (and no overhead at all).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pass the DbContext as parameter:

```
public class ControllerHelper
{
    public void DeleteChain(int? chainId, UranusContext db)
    {
        var chain = db.Chains.Include(c => c.Sheets)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChainId == chainId);

        // Removes sheets (children)
        foreach (var sheet in chain.Sheets.ToList())
        {
            DeleteSheet(sheet.SheetId, db);
        }

        db.Chains.Remove(chain);
    }

    public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId, UranusContext db)
    {
        var sheet = db.Sheets.Include(s => s.FileDetails)
            .Include(s => s.SheetsCounties)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SheetId == sheetId);

        foreach (var fileDetails in sheet.FileDetails.ToList())
        {
            db.FileDetails.Remove(fileDetails);
        }

        foreach (var sheetsCounties in sheet.SheetsCounties.ToList())
        {
            db.SheetsCounties.Remove(sheetsCounties);
        }

        db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
public void Foo(int? someChainId, int? someSheetId, bool required = false)
{
    ControllerHelper hlp = new ControllerHelper();
    using (UranusContext db = new UranusContext())
    {
        hlp.DeleteChain(someChainId);

        if(_required)
            hlp.DeleteSheet(int? someSheetId);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the using pattern and passing the context as a parameter to the DeleteSheet method thus:

```
    public class ControllerHelper
{
    public void DeleteChain(int? chainId)
    {
    using (UranusContext db = new UranusContext())
    {
            var chain = db.Chains.Include(c => c.Sheets)
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChainId == chainId);

            // Removes sheets (children)
            foreach (var sheet in chain.Sheets.ToList())
            {
                DeleteSheet(sheet.SheetId, db);
            }

            db.Chains.Remove(chain);
            db.SaveChanges();
    }
    }

    public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId, UranusContext db)
    {
        var sheet = db.Sheets.Include(s => s.FileDetails)
            .Include(s => s.SheetsCounties)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SheetId == sheetId);

        foreach (var fileDetails in sheet.FileDetails.ToList())
        {
            db.FileDetails.Remove(fileDetails);
        }

        foreach (var sheetsCounties in sheet.SheetsCounties.ToList())
        {
            db.SheetsCounties.Remove(sheetsCounties);
        }

        db.Sheets.Remove(sheet);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This way, you can be sure that the context is being disposed only when all the deletes have been completed.  I always try to avoid having more than one context in use at a time, I've been badly burned by that before!

Comment: The problem I run into is that I call DeleteSheet by itself in my controller class, which makes me have to create another DbContext there to call it this way.  I still don't like it, but maybe I'm being picky.

Comment: Solves the problem but calls ' SaveChanges()` `chain.Sheets`-times which can be a problem if `SaveChanges()` has any overloads.

Comment: Write an override of DeleteSheet which takes the Id and context, and keep the one you have for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In your design a `ControllerHelper` is a composition of a `UranusContext`. This means that you designed that as long as the `ControllerHelper` exists, the `UranusContext` exists, and you want the `UranusCibtext` to cease existing as soon as the `ControllerHelper` does not exist anymore.

By making it a composition you promise the users of your class that all your functions work as long as your class exists. Therefore, you should not `Dispose()` the `UranusContext` in any of your functions until your users inform you that they don't need your functionality anymore. This can be done by making your `ControllerHelper` IDisposable

If any class implements IDisposable, the designer of this class encourages the user to call `Dispose()` as soon as possible after he doesn't need the functionality of the object anymore.

In your case the code would be:

```
public class ControllerHelper : IDisposable()
{
    private UranusContext db = new UranusContext();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.db != null)
        {
            this.db.Dispose();
            this.db = null;
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void DeleteChain(int? chainId)
    {
       // Do what you need to do, but don't Dispose()
       // nor use using, we want db to be functional
    }
    public void DeleteSheet(int? sheetId)
    {
       // Do what you need to do, but don't Dispose()
       // nor use using, we want db to be functional
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
using (var controllerHelper = new ControllerHelper())
{
    // call functions from controllerhelper
}
// the controllerHelper is not needed anymore, Dispose() is called automatically
// and thus db is Disposed
```

Comment: I like this more. Would having ``using (UranusContext db = new UranusContext())`` ensure proper disposal?  I followed @Evk 's solution, but I'm still dubious of passing UranusContext as a parameter and it not being disposed properly.